# Goodness of fit through Kolmogorov–Smirnov test using R Language

Tags: r

Goodness-of-fit tests allow us to test if the empirical distribution of a variable (here city sizes) follows a known theoretical distribution (here a Pareto distribution).

The null hypothesis of this test is that  the postulated distribution is acceptable whereas the alternative hypothesis is that the data do not follow this distribution.

I want to program this in the R language. I want to do Monte Carlo simulation to check goodness of fit for my data, which consists of USA city sizes.

My empirical distribution here is that of US city sizes. I want to test whether my data conforms to the Pareto distribution.  In the above given image all functions are defined for calculating the P.value. I know there is a package called `"dgof"` and that the command for running the Kolmogorov-Smirnow test is `ks.test(x, y,alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"))`, but I don't know how to apply it to the situation above.

```
data<-read.csv("C:/Users/Shah/Desktop/US data 452 cities 2000.csv") 
attach(data) 
y<-Population 
require(dgof) 
x<-rlnorm(100,5,1) 
ks.test(x, y,alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"), 
   exact = NULL, tol=1e-8, simulate.p.value=TRUE, B=1000)
```

Comment: Some remarks: Firstly, I beleive your question is off-topic for StackOverflow and might be better suited for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com). Secondly, before asking, you should make some research; R is a great piece of software, but it requires some hard work to use it; I recommend you find a good R tutorial (my personal recommendation: [Quick-R](http://statmethods.net)).

Comment: Thirdly: You can google for some answers before asking. Two recommended readings: [Fitting distributions with R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf) and the afore mentioned [Quick R tutorial](http://statmethods.net)... and [this other article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i have already searched for it on stackflow. but this issue has not been discussed yet on stackflow. if you can help then please . .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics and maybe should be migrated to http://stats.stackexchange.com . Also, it does not show evidence of effort on finding a solution before asking the question.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the only information source... Specifically on R, there are many other places to find solutions, specially if you are new to it. Check the links I've provided in my comments. Also, questions related to statistics may be better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com , and may be already some answers there.

Comment: i have already done reading of this " Fitting distributions with R and the afore mentioned Quick R tutorial... and this other article". .  But this irrelevant to my issue.

Comment: How is it irrelevant? Specifically Ricci's paper contains examples on how to use many goodness-of-fit tests, KS test among them. Read it again. No one here (not me, at least) is going to write the code for you. You need to show some effort, you need to help yourself before asking for help. Try to write the code, try to make it work, and if you face *specific* issues, come back here and ask specific questions. Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: you are right sir
i have done this 
data<-read.csv("C:/Users/Shah/Desktop/US data 452 cities 2000.csv")
attach(data)
y<-Population
require(dgof)
x<-rlnorm(100,5,1)
ks.test(x, y,alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
exact = NULL, tol=1e-8, simulate.p.value=TRUE, B=1000)
can you correct it ?

Answer (score 2):

First, understand how the `ks.test()` function works. [Read the reference for ks.test()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/ks.test.html).

So, let's say you have the data loaded to a `data.frame` called `data`, and you want to perform the KS test on a column named `population`, and you want to test wether your data is fitted by a pareto distribution. Notice that the `actuar` package contains the two-parameter pareto distribution. You need, of course, to estimate the value of such parameters (I leave that to you).

Now, simply do this:

```
library(actuar)
library(stats)
ks.test(data$population, 'ppareto', shape=yourShapeEstimate, scale=yourScaleEstimate)
```

Comment: One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  data$population
D = 0.8335, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
i got the following results. Which Shows this data do not follows pareto distribution, whereas in an research article the used ths same data and conclude that this data follows the pareto distribution. .so i am little bit confuse , am i doing it in proper way or wrong way.

Comment: While I think some of the previous comments about your question were a bit harsh, questions about the results probably do belong on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: yes there answers were harsh, i think if people do not want to help then they don not have any right to disgrace the the person who is asking the question. my posted has been shifted on on stats.stackexchange.com but there i received the same kind of useless comments.

Comment: Consider using alternative goodness-of-fit tests... the chi-squared test is also a good test. And take into consideration this: "For both this test (KS) and the Anderson-Darling test [...] the critical values are only correct when the null hypothesis completely specifies the model. When the data set is used to estimate parameters for the null hipothezised distribution [...] the correct critical value is smaller" (Klugman, S. "Loss Models")

Comment: I recommend you don't take any anticipated conclussions: do the full statistical analysis: Make a histogram and compare it to some distributions. Read some texts on the topic. I recommend you the afore mentioned "Loss Models" by Stuart Klugman *et al*. Also, check the estimates of your parameters. I might have been harsh in my answers, but that doesn't make them wrong. If you are trying to solve a problem (in statistics or any other field), you need to work hard. Do your exploratory analysis and build your own conclussions.